# ssh Public key Authentication different home directory structure permissions

Tags: authentication, ssh, key, public, authorized-keys

I have few user accounts with home in the following format.
/data/test/{user1, user2,...}  and the public key configured , but the still prompts for password.  I have

```
/data/test/ -- 775

/data/test/user1 -- 775

/data/test/user1/.ssh -- 700

/data/test/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys - 600
```

What should be the permissions for each directory in my case `/data/test/{user1, user2,...}`  .  also , the users have a uid > 20000.

Answer (score 0):

Check messages in  /var/log/auth.log

I assume, your problem because of directories /data and /data/test has permissions to group for write.

I would like remind: all directories in the path myst be belong to root, and do not have permissions for another users or groups to modify them.